# Page number in the middle of the page's top

Tags: page-numbering, page

I found out how to place the page number at the top of the page, but how to place it in the middle of the top? Now it's on the right edge.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{amsbsy}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    % Alternative geometry
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=2.5cm}
    \geometry{right=1.cm}
    \geometry{top=2cm}
    \geometry{bottom=2cm}
    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[c]{{\thepage}}
    \fancyheadoffset{0mm}
    \fancyfootoffset{0mm}
    \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
        \fancyhf{}
        \rhead{\thepage}}
    
    \begin{document} 
    \chapter*{\centerline{Intro}}
\label{Intro} \addtocontents{toc} {
\hbox to\textwidth{ 
{\bf Intro}
\hfil
\pageref{Intro}}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I just compiled your code, and the page number is centered already.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I added some text between begin and end and now there is a problem

Comment: And by the way, before adding text page number was in the middle of the text length, not in the middle of page

Comment: \rhead mean right head, for center use \chead.

Comment: and don't use things like \centerline in a chapter title, and \bf is outdated since 30 years, use \textbf{bold} or {\bfseries bold}. The \hbox doesn't make much sense, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your code:

```
...
    \chead{\thepage}}

\begin{document} 
...
```

[image]